# How to remove UIImageView from Index?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a puzzle game where I added all the image views into `NSMutableArray` but I want to delete its first array which is at Index 0 my code is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var allImageViews : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    var xCen :CGFloat  = 53
    var yCen :CGFloat = 94

    for v in 0...2{

        for h in 0...2{

            let filename = String(format: "kat_%02i.gif", h+v*3)
            let Image = UIImage(named: filename)
            let myImageView = UIImageView(image: Image)
            myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 189)
            myImageView.center = CGPointMake(xCen, yCen)
            myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            allImageViews.addObject(myImageView)
            self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
            xCen += 106
        }
        xCen = 53
        yCen += 189
    }
    allImageViews.removeObjectAtIndex(0)

}
```

I think I remove object from Index but Its still appear when I run project so can anybody tell me how can I remove the first image from superview?

Comment: You are adding the image twice. Remove one of the          allImageViews.addObject(myImageView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `removeFromSuperview` on the view before removing it from your array:

```
allImageViews[0].removeFromSuperview()
allImageViews.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
```

If you use a Swift array instead of an `NSMutableArray` then you get more type
safety and you can take advantage of the fact that `removeAtIndex()` returns
the removed element:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var allImageViews : [UIImageView] = []

    var xCen :CGFloat  = 53
    var yCen :CGFloat = 94

    for v in 0...2{

        for h in 0...2{

            let filename = String(format: "kat_%02i.gif", h+v*3)
            let Image = UIImage(named: filename)
            let myImageView = UIImageView(image: Image)
            myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 189)
            myImageView.center = CGPointMake(xCen, yCen)
            myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            allImageViews.append(myImageView)
            self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
            xCen += 106
        }
        xCen = 53
        yCen += 189
    }

    allImageViews.removeAtIndex(0).removeFromSuperview()
}
```